# Build only git tags in wercker

Tags: git, wercker

Is it possible to limit a pipelines to tagged commits similar to gitlab-ci "only: [tags]"?

The UI only allows the options "Chain Pipeline" or to start it on git push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipelines are triggered by git hooks. You can assign a hook to the pipeline through the Workflow UI. A hook is just a simple script that returns 0 if the build is to happen, or anything else if it shouldn't happen. So you can check to see if the commit is tagged like this:

```
[ `git tag -l --points-at HEAD` | grep "YourTagsRegex" ] && exit 0
exit 1
```

Note that I haven't tested this. Hopefully that's close though.

Comment: But this way, the run is marked as failed and a notification is emailed every time a normal commit is pushed to the repo.

Comment: It would be failed if you ran this in the pipeline (because of the non-zero exit value). But when you configure it as a hook it shouldn't; it should simply not start the pipeline, so there won't be a success or a failure. If you're seeing different behaviour, you should get in touch with gitlab.